# Change the Product View in Magento 2.1 for a specific Category

Tags: magento

I need to customise the product view for all products in a specific category.

I want to remove the product image and information on right hand side (in red).
I then need the product info (circled in yellow) to fill the width (Blue line).[Colour coded screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGBaK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following steps:

1.You need to create a custom module ans create `setup/installData.php` file and add this

```
<?php

namespace Test\Customcategorymode\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'show_mode', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Show Mode',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'source' => 'W3solver\Customcategorymode\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Showmode',
            'sort_order' => 102,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'Display Settings',
                ]
        );


        $setup->endSetup();
    }

}
```

2.To view the show mode field in admin panel UI components needs to be created in `view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <fieldset name="display_settings">
            <field name="show_mode">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">W3solver\Customcategorymode\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Showmode</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">102</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Show Mode</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>   
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

3.Also add a source model in `Model/Category/Attribute/Source/Showmode.php` and write below function:-

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Test\Customcategorymode\Model\Category\Attribute\Source;

/**
 * Catalog category landing page attribute source
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class ShowMode extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
     public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = [
                ['value' => 'type1', 'label' => __('type1')],
                ['value' => 'type2', 'label' => __('type2')],
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

4.Now you need to override all those files which you want to change

5.Add these conditions to all product files where you want changes:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product




        $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
        if(count($cats) ){
            $firstCategoryId = $cats[0];
            $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($firstCategoryId);
        }

   if ($category->getShowMode() == 'type1') {
            // add your code
   } else {
       // add your code
   }
```